# Apache Flink Dynamic Pipeline

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm working on creating a framework to allow customers to create their own plugins to my software built on Apache Flink. I've outlined in a snippet below what I'm trying to get working (just as a proof of concept), however I'm getting a `org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.` error when trying to upload it.

I want to be able to branch the input stream into `x` number of different pipelines, then having those combine together into a single output. What I have below is just my simplified version I'm starting with.

```
public class ContentBase {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "kf-service:9092");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "varnost-content");

    // Setup up execution environment and get stream from Kafka
    StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataStream<ObjectNode> logs = see.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>("log-input",
                    new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), properties).setStartFromLatest())
            .map((MapFunction<ObjectNode, ObjectNode>) jsonNodes -> (ObjectNode) jsonNodes.get("value"));


    // Create a new List of Streams, one for each "rule" that is being executed
    // For now, I have a simple custom wrapper on flink's `.filter` function in `MyClass.filter`
    List<String> codes = Arrays.asList("404", "200", "500");
    List<DataStream<ObjectNode>> outputs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String code : codes) {
      outputs.add(MyClass.filter(logs, "response", code));
    }

    // It seemed as though I needed a seed DataStream to union all others on 
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode seedObject = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree("{\"start\":\"true\"");
    DataStream<ObjectNode> alerts = see.fromElements(seedObject);

    // Union the output of each "rule" above with the seed object to then output
    for (DataStream<ObjectNode> output : outputs) {
      alerts.union(output);
    }


    // Convert to string and sink to Kafka
    alerts.map((MapFunction<ObjectNode, String>) ObjectNode::toString)
            .addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer011<>("kf-service:9092", "log-output", new SimpleStringSchema()));
    see.execute();
  }
}
```

*I can't figure out how to get the actual error out of the Flink web interface to add that information here*

Comment: As a side note... I'm not a Java guy, and haven't used it since college, so don't judge me too hard lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few errors I found.

<strike>1) A Stream Execution Environment can only have one input (apparently? I could be wrong) so adding the `.fromElements` input was not good</strike>

2) I forgot all DataStreams are immutable so the .union operation creates a new DataStream output.

The final result ended up being much simpler

```
public class ContentBase {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "kf-service:9092");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "varnost-content");

    // Setup up execution environment and get stream from Kafka
    StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataStream<ObjectNode> logs = see.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>("log-input",
                    new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), properties).setStartFromLatest())
            .map((MapFunction<ObjectNode, ObjectNode>) jsonNodes -> (ObjectNode) jsonNodes.get("value"));


    // Create a new List of Streams, one for each "rule" that is being executed
    // For now, I have a simple custom wrapper on flink's `.filter` function in `MyClass.filter`
    List<String> codes = Arrays.asList("404", "200", "500");
    List<DataStream<ObjectNode>> outputs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String code : codes) {
      outputs.add(MyClass.filter(logs, "response", code));
    }

    Optional<DataStream<ObjectNode>> alerts = outputs.stream().reduce(DataStream::union);


    // Convert to string and sink to Kafka
    alerts.map((MapFunction<ObjectNode, String>) ObjectNode::toString)
            .addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer011<>("kf-service:9092", "log-output", new SimpleStringSchema()));
    see.execute();
  }
}
```

Comment: A single StreamExecutionEnvironment can have as many inputs/sources as you like -- there's no arbitrary limit.

Answer (score 0):

The code you post cannot be compiled through because of the last part code (i.e., converting to string). You mixed up the java stream API `map` with Flink one. Change it to

```
alerts.get().map(ObjectNode::toString);
```

can fix it.

Good luck.